# spring mvc error is not showing in the fields

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my spring mvc project I want to save users name and home to the database..

So I have done this:--

**Detail--- Model class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "details")
public class Detail{

private String name;
private String home;
public Detail(String name, String home) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.home = home;
    }

---setters and getters with   @NotEmpty @Column   annotations------------


}
```

### **Dao class**

```
@Transactional
@Repository("detailDao")
public class DetailDaoImpl implements DeatilDao{

@Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


     public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }
public void saveDetail(Detail detail) throws SQLException {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(detail);
    }


}
```

### **service class**

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public Detail saveDetail(String name,  String home) throws SQLException {


        Detail detail = new Detail(name,home);


        detailDao.saveDetail(detail);


        return detail;


    }
```

### **Controller class**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/detailsave")
public class DetailController {



    @Autowired
    private DetailService detailService;
    @Autowired
    private DetailDao detailDao;



        /*when call the only /submit*/   

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String detail(@ModelAttribute("Detail") Detail detail,HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,ModelMap model) {
        return "detailsave";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/savefields", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String dosave(@ModelAttribute("Detail")  Detail detail,BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,Model model,HttpSession session) {

             ModelAndView mav;
    mav = new ModelAndView("savefields");

        if (result.hasErrors()) {

        mav.addObject("detail", detail);
        return mav;
    }

        try{
            detail=  detailService.saveDetail(detail.getName(), detail.getHome());

            if(detail != null){


                session.setAttribute("detailId", detail.getDetailId());
                return new ModelAndView("successpage");
            }
        }
            catch(ConstraintViolationException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
                 return mav;
            }

    return mav;


}
}
```

and **jsp page** is:---

```
  <c:url var="save" value="/detailsave/savefields" />

       <form:form modelAttribute="detail" method="POST" action="${save}">


        <table>

            <tr>
              <td><form:label path="Name">*Name:</form:label></td>
               <td><form:input path="Name"/> </td>

            </tr>


              <tr>
               <td></td>
                <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/></td>

            </tr>

          <tr>
              <td><form:label path="home">*Home:</form:label></td>
               <td><form:input path="home"/></td>
            </tr>


              <tr>
               <td></td>
                <td><form:errors path="home" cssClass="error"/></td>
            </tr>

              <tr>   

                <td></td>
              <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /> </td>
            </tr>

      </table>  

    </form:form>
```

**viewresolver**

```
<beans xmlns ------so many url types--  >

<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/classes/jdbc.properties" />
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.salini.mvc" /> 


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />


    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**"  location="/resources/" /> 

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:/messages" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>




    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
         <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.salini.mvc.model.Detail</value>
                    <value>com.salini.mvc.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>


        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Now the problem is when I submit the form without fill the form it needs to show error in the page..But the error is not showing.its just still same page..

Again When I am getting any error(exception) from database Its not showing .its still same page..

But if the form has no error then it is going to the success page..

My question is why error is not showing???

If I use `@valid` annotation in my controller..then error is showing(not the database error) but it is not going to the success page though I don't have any error..why??

Comment: You can handle exception in DAO layer and throw it to controller. In controller you have to decide what to do with exception (i.e show error page or transfer somewhere)

Comment: I already have tried..I have posted the new code..What I have tried..But the problem is When I use that code, if there is no error it is still in the same page..

Comment: Can you share detail of View Resolver settings.

Comment: yes,ofcourse..I have posted viewresolver..

Comment: Please specify your view location and type like below                                      <property name="prefix">          <value>/WEB-INF/</value>

        </property>

        <property name="suffix">

            <value>.jsp</value>

        </property>

Comment: But I am using tiles..I need to use:--

<bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">

Answer (score 1):

without @**valid** annotation your **BindingResult** object will be allways empty because the object will not be validated by spring framework.

But when saving object hibernate will throw **ConstraintViolationException** because the attributes name and home could not be empty, and when you **catch** this exception you send to view "**savefields**", but the object **BindingResult** still **empty** so no message error was showing in your page.

```
       ModelAndView mav;
       mav = new ModelAndView("savefields");

       catch(ConstraintViolationException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
             return mav;
        }
```

if the form has no error, so the object will be saved successfully and you send to view **successpage**

```
        if(detail != null){


            session.setAttribute("detailId", detail.getDetailId());
            return new ModelAndView("successpage");
        }
```

With @Valid annotation the object will be validated by spring framework.

if the form has any error your **BindingResult** object will be full so you send to view **savefields** and not **successpage**

```
  mav = new ModelAndView("savefields");

    if (result.hasErrors()) {

    mav.addObject("detail", detail);
    return mav;
}
```